# Why I can see my WKWebView while its frame set to .zero

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview

So I was trying to load webView instead of storyboard this way

```
    override func loadView() {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration( )
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration : config)


    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    view = webView


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://vk.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true 
}
```

It seems obviously that webView's frame is zero i a should not be able to see anything on screen but i see full webView window. Please maybe I did not took into account something important?

Comment: pls add webview in main view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of set the webView as the main view of your view controller, add it as a subview

```
override func loadView() {
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration( )
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration : config)


    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    view = UIView()
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

By default, the `view` property of a view controller takes full height and width.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to use `WKWebView` as the root view of a view controller. It’s just that the frame property of the root view will be ignored, as it is determined by the parent view controller or a presentation controller.